# jQuery submit handler does not submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form which needs to be submitted after validating and confirming the request.

But when I click ok in the confirmation alert pop up it doesn't do anything.

Below is the code:

```
$("#form").validate({

    onkeyup: false,
    ignore: 'input:hidden',
    async: false,
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
        },
    },
    messages: {
        username: {
            required: "Please enter a username",
        },
    },
    submitHandler: function validateUser(){

        if(confirm('Are you sure??')){
        return true;
        }else {
        return false;
        }
        },
    errorElement: "span",
    wrapper: "span",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent());
        error.css({
            color: 'red',
            display: 'block'
        });
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    }

});
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what your problem is? Show an example. We need to see the context. How do you even call .validate()?

Comment: Please, show us your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simplified version

```
$("#form").validate({    
    onkeyup: false,
    ignore: 'input:hidden',
    async: false,
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
        },
    },
    messages: {
        username: {
            required: "Please enter a username",
        },
    },
    submitHandler: function(){
        return confirm('Are you sure??');
        },
    errorElement: "span",
    wrapper: "span",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent());
        error.css({
            color: 'red',
            display: 'block'
        });
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
submitHandler: function(form){

    if(confirm('Are you sure??')){
       form.submit(); // or $(form).ajaxSubmit(); if you use ajax
    }else {
       return false;
    }
},
```